# Using ST_Distance in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, plpgsql, shapefile

I have a table with id, x ,y value ,I need to find the distance between two points using a function in posgresql.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distances(lat1 float, lon1 float, lat2 float, lon2 float)
RETURNS float AS $dist$
    BEGIN
        SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(lat1 lon1 )')
, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(lat2 lon2)'), false);
    END;
$dist$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But error throws out when i pass the value:
[image]

Kindly give me a sloution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things:

- You were trying to concatenate a variable in a string without a `||`
- The right order is **lon lat**, not **lat lon**
- You do not need a function for this. A simple query with the [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) function would suffice

But in case you need it for other purposes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distances(lat1 float, lon1 float, lat2 float, lon2 float)
RETURNS float AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (
  SELECT 
    ST_Distance(
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon1,lat1),4326),
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon2,lat2),4326), false));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Otherwise this SQL query would do:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(51.23,8.83),4326),
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(51.24,8.55),4326), false);
```

Cheers

Further reading:

- [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)